# How to automatically add server date to a document on insert?

Tags: mongodb, rest

I am using REST API (RESTHEART) to insert new entries into MongoDB. I have a JSON to insert

```
{
    "name": "test"
}
```

When i insert said document, MongoDB automatically creates _id field for my document, which is a good thing. But i also want Mongo (or restheart) to automatically create a field "date" with a current server timestamp. How do i achieve this? I don't want to put a date from client on my server, and i don't want to use the built-in date in "_id" field. I want to have my every database entry to be signed with timestamp on insertion. Oddly enough, i haven't found any way of doing this simple task. Is this even possible? I really don't want to write my own server from scratch just so my users can post JSON documents to my database. I have only managed to insert server date by specifying invalid JSON in my post request.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "date": new Date()
}
```

This works, but this is clearly the bad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique field or combination of fields (i.e. if the document being inserted does not match a document already in the collection), and you are using MongoDB 4.2+, you could upsert the document instead of insert, and use the `$$NOW` operator to inject the current server time.

```
db.collection.update(
    { "name": "test" },
    [{$set: {createdAt:"$$NOW"}}],
    {upsert: true}
)
```

Testing that with my local cluster, the inserted document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60820c671de6b9f1d245f63e"),
    "name" : "test",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-04-22T23:53:10.721Z")
}
```